# Why does my PCSpim MIPS program that sums up integers except integers > 1000 loads but does not run?

Tags: mips

The output should be "sum = 11" but with my previous versions the outputs were wrong. Here is all the code I personally did from the whole program...

```
      addi $t4, $t4, 1000

      la $t0, numbers          # $t0 will point to the elements
      la $t1, count         # exit loop when $t1 == 0
      lw $t1, 0($t1)             # $t1 is the size of array (in words)
      addi $t2, $t2, 0       # i = 0


loop:   
      lw $t3,($t0)           # load next word from array    


      blt $t3, $t4, skip       # skip if a[i] < 1000

      add $t2, $t2, $t3

skip:

      addiu $t0,$t0, 4         # decrement counter
      addiu $t2,$t2,1            # increment pointer by word

      bne $t2, $t1, loop       # loop if i != count size

      la $a0,ans1               # syscall to print out
      li $v0,4                  # the sum message
      syscall

      move $a0, $t2          # print sum result
      li $v0,1
      syscall
```

Comment: Is this the complete code?  If so, you're missing a `.text` directive (and possibly a `main` label as well).  Further, there is nothing in `$t4` when you source it on the first line, so use `$0` there instead, same goes for `$t2`.  You're doing i += 0 not i = 0.  Is `$t2` your sum variable or your counter?  You're using it for both and it can't do that double duty.

Comment: I did not put the whole code here, sorry. I used your advice and
a previous save that used code lines like:
-add $t1, $t1, -1       # decreases the whole array count (size) by minus 1
-addi $t4, $0, 1000
-bge $t3, $t4, skip     # skip the array index if i >= 1000
-and so on and I finally got it to work.

I believed I was so close to getting it right I ended up almost being more and more wrong! Thanks for your help.